# How do i Receive input which I put into my two dimensional array in c#?

Tags: c#, datatable, multidimensional-array

I am making a two dimensional array (soccer matrix)I have already made my arrays, datacolumn and rows.

How do i make my matrix like this below?
and get the right input everywhere

```
2010-2011     England   Germany   Holland   Spain   Germany   Russia   Japan

England         x

Germany                    x

Holland                             x

Spain                                         x

Germany                                               x

Russia                                                          x

Japan                                                                    x
```

This all will be made into a console application.

Best regards,

Comment: On SO, we usually refrain from using pastebin. Include code directly in your question. Thanks

Comment: Are you displaying it through the console?

Comment: yes i am displaying it through the console.   Oh sorry about that then - I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int rows = 8;
int colums = 8;
String[,] data = new String[colums, rows];
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

for(; y < rows; y++)
{
    for (; x < colums; x++)
    {
        Console.Write(data[x, y] + " ");
        if (x == (colums - 1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
    x = 0;
}

int userSelectedHomeTeam
int userSelectedAwayTeaM

Console.WriteLine("Select home team by the number")
for(int i = 1; i < colums; i++)
{   
    Console.WriteLine(data[i, 0] + " " + i)
}
str = Console.ReadLine(); 
userSelectedHomeTeam = Int32.Parse(str);

Console.WriteLine("Select away team by the number")
for(int i = 1; i < colums; i++)
{   
    Console.WriteLine(data[i, 0] + " " + i)
}
str = Console.ReadLine(); 
userSelectedAwayTeam = Int32.Parse(str);

Console.WriteLine("Write user input")
str = Console.ReadLine(); 
data[userSelectedHomeTeam , userSelectedAwayTeam ] = str;
```

Comment: thnx man appreciate it - but how do i get my input from the user correctly under neath each team?

Comment: i have made a change, i am not completely sure that i understood it right...and my code is written in notepad...but i think it will work

Comment: He gives errors for str  and some of the "i" - which i am trying to fix

Comment: add a "+" before the i :) i is going to show what number the user should write to select a team...

Comment: oh thnx i see that now. And it gives errors to str - but I don't know what the parse function does - so i dont know how to declare it

Comment: And one last thing it says that int32 does not excist in my context - why is that ?

Comment: int32.Parse converts a string to a number.. does big "P" on Parse solve it :)?...anyway this solution has no safety what so ever...if the user writes a letter instead of a number the program will crash

Comment: aah its Int32 and not int32 :D  thnx

Answer (score 0):

To output it all you need do is:

```
int numberRows = dataArray.GetUpperBound(0);
int numberColumns = dataArray.GetUpperBound(1);

for (int i = 0; i <= numberRows ; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= numberColumns ; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("({0,8}) ", dataArray[i, j]));
    }
Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Just use string padding for the output, so that each column data appears under the correct team name, i've used 8 you will need to adjust this for however wide each column is.

Comment: I tried yours - i got a total of 15 rows and 15 columns - but when I look at my output, for each team it gives the teamname on the top and followed with 14 <    >  empty arrays and that for every team.